# Default list values

Tags: r

I'm iteratively counting the occurrences of some values in a list:

```
counts <- list()
lst <- list(1, 4, 6, 10)

for (i in lst) {
  arbitraryKey <- toString(i %% 3)
  arbitraryCondition <- i %% 2 == 0

  if (!(arbitraryKey %in% names(counts))) {
    counts[[arbitraryKey]] <- 0
  }
  if (arbitraryCondition) {
    counts[[arbitraryKey]] <- counts[[arbitraryKey]] + 1
  }
}
```

Is there a way to obviate the need to initialize the missing the elements in the list?

```
  if (!(arbitraryKey %in% names(counts))) {
    counts[[arbitraryKey]] <- 0
  }
```

Perhaps this can be achieved through converting NULL to 0, or by giving the list a default value?

Comment: This seems like you are clearly coming from a non-functional language and are trying to copy code over to R. R does not have default list values. Normally you could apply function over your list then summarize. Does this just need to be generalizable for any key and conditioning function? Perhaps we can suggest better ways that won't need default list values.

Comment: While the individual steps I'm performing are perhaps too involved to describe here, I appreciate your feedback and I will work to try to restructure my code in a way more adequately supported by R.